# Escaping environment variable names in VSTS

Tags: build, environment-variables, azure-devops

In my build configuration I have say `MY.VAR` variable defined on **Variables** tab. In VSTS all build variables are automatically available as environment variables accessible in task steps which is pretty nice. The problem is VSTS converts dot characters to underscores so `MY.VAR` becomes `MY_VAR` in environments variables. Which is just stupid as I can have any number of dots in my environment variables:

```
set MY.VAR=my-numeric-value
```

How to make VSTS to not convert dots to underscores? Any escaping trick? Or, how can I set `MY.VAR` environment variable so that it's available to every task in my build?

I tried `${env:MY.VAR} = "my-numeric-value"` powershell command which works just fine but the variable is not persisted to the subsequent tasks.

Comment: You can't control that behavior. What specific problem is it causing for you? You already know the solution to the problem you're describing: Use underscores when accessing them as environment variables.

Comment: My codebase relies on some env variables, some of them have dots in their names. I need to run tests during a build and modify those variables depending on what environment the tests run on. So I'm trying to find a better solution than renaming those names in the code and modifying variables on a number of machines where the system currently runs.

Comment: @UserControl Can't environment variable `ENV:MY_VAR` or user defined variable `$(MY.VAR)` be used instead?

Comment: I can't use VSTS variables in my code, can I? And renaming the variables in the codebase is just too much efforts at this point.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to change that behavior.
2. You can use [VSTS Task Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to set the variable value so that the value will be available in subsequent tasks.
   [image]